# What is the equivalent to `res.json({}, 'ready')`

Tags: typescript, express

I'm trying to convert some tests for an application to TypeScript, but there a slight problem, `res.json()` currently only takes one parameter, but there is a deprecated method that takes 2 arguments.

Now, according to express' source, either one of the parameters has to be a number, which isn't the case in the application's code.

This is the code line in question `res.json({}, 'ready')`

And here it is in more context:

```js
import SSE = require('connect-sse');
import express = require('express');
const sse = SSE();
const app = express();
app.get('/events', sse, (req, res) => {
    res.json({}, 'ready')
})
```

Comment: You can always force it to work by using `any`, or force casting `res.json()` to a different function signature. Or if you think the definitions really don't match the actual function, might be worth opening a PR / issue to get the definitions updated, so they don't remove the deprecated variant from the definitions until it's actually removed from the source.

Comment: I should definately do that.

Comment: I'm not seeing any code in their source that matches what you have, though. What version of express are you using? https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/response.js#L239-L268

Comment: I've added a little bit more code around that line so more information can be taken.